# how to show available wifi networks on a button click in android?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I'm working to build a simple android 8.0+ application which shows the Wi-Fi scan result in a list within that app.
I've tried all the given solutions in stack overflow, but I didn't get result'for listing the available networks on the screen. Following is the code I've tried to get the result.

```
package com.example.wifi_application;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button buttonScan;
    private int size = 0;
    private List<ScanResult> results;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonScan = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scanWifi();
            }
        });

        listView = findViewById(R.id.wifiList);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

       // assert wifiManager != null;
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi is disabled ... We need to enable it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        scanWifi();
    }

    private void scanWifi() {
        arrayList.clear();
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();
        Log.d("WifScanner", "scanWifi");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning WiFi ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("WifScanner", "onReceive");
            results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            size = results.size();
            unregisterReceiver(this);
            try {
                while (size >= 0) {
                    size--;
                    arrayList.add(results.get(size).SSID);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("WifScanner", "Exception: " + e);
            }

        }
    };
}
```

this is the XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wifiList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.97"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="Scan WiFi"/>

</LinearLayout>
```